# Why is my python program not working?

Tags: python-2.7

```
import time
import random
target = random.randrange(1, 3, 2)
print target  #for debug reasons
time.sleep(5)
shot = raw_input("Enter a random number")
while shot != target:
   print "n0pe"
   shot = raw_input("Enter a random number")
else:
    print "you won"
```

as i was testing this funny game it just always said n0pe even if i was saying the right number. I cant figure out whats wrong with it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`target` is an integer value. `raw_input()` returns a string. In python, strings and integers will never be equal to each other.

For example:

```
print 1 == "1"
# prints "False"
```

You'll want to convert the user input to an integer using `int()` before doing the comparison.

```
import time
import random
target = random.randrange(1, 3, 2)
print target  #for debug reasons
time.sleep(5)
shot = int(raw_input("Enter a random number"))
while shot != target:
   print "n0pe"
   shot = int(raw_input("Enter a random number"))
else:
    print "you won"
```

Comment: **THANKS** I dont know why i didnt think of that ;D

Answer (score 0):

The comparison is not right. You are comparing a string with integer.

Try this:

```
import time
import random
target = random.randrange(1, 3, 2)
time.sleep(5)
shot = raw_input("Enter a random number")
while True:
    if int(shot) != target:
        print "n0pe"
        shot = raw_input("Enter a random number")
    else:
        print "you won"
        break
```